# Is it possible to download the entire react app and then load it on to the webview?

Tags: android, reactjs, android-studio, caching, webview

I created an android application that loads the react app on to the webview. However, the react app has some pages that has videos on it. The issue here is this application is supposed to work when there is little or no internet at all after the application is setup initially (meaning there is going to be a good internet connection when the application is launched for the first time). I am wondering if there is a way to download the entire webapp, save it on the device somewhere and then use webview to load it from there rather from an external URL.
Also, if there is a better way to approach this problem any help would be appreciated.
So far I have tried to cache the webview with little improvement in the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Write a native loader app.  Have it download all the files.  Make sure the files all use relative references to each other.  Then once downloaded, load it into the webview.  Probably easiest to zip them all into 1 file and download the zip and extract it to local storage.

If you include the files with the loader as well, you could use the code:

```
if (has internet) 
  save to disk from internet //Can use cache headers to see if there's an update and if not skip the download
if (!has on disk)
  copy files from APK to disk
load from disk
```

That way it will work even if you don't have an internet connection the first time.